# maven multi-module project not running

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have developed a multi-module project with Java spring boot on IntelliJ.
This is runnable in the IDE without any problem via 'run Application' where 'Application' is my SpringBootApplication and located in a submodule of the parent module.

Now I want to run this system on a server and I am unable to get it running. I tried

> mvn spring-boot:run

and I get following error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.application.Application
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.application.Application

I also tried other commands like

> mvn clean package

where I get errors saying that packages from the 'shared_model' (succesfully compiled - because no dependencies of other modules) do not exist (although they exist), while trying to compile 'aggregate'-package (depending on 'shared_model'), e.g.:

> [ERROR] /.../aggregates/src/main/java/com/example/aggregates/.../.java:[3,52] package com.example.shared_model.... does not exist

> [ERROR] /.../aggregates/src/main/java/com/example/aggregates/.../.java:[13,12] cannot find symbol

The file structure looks like this:

```
main
├── adapters-input
├── adapters-output
├── aggregates
├── application
├── application-services
└── shared_model
```

Where every package has its own pom-file.

The pom of the parent module looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>main</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <java-version>11</java-version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <modules>
        <module>adapters-output</module>
        <module>adapters-input</module>
        <module>application-services</module>
        <module>aggregates</module>
        <module>application</module> <!-- location of main class -->
        <module>shared_model</module>
    </modules>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.example.application.Application</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The pom of the 'application'-package looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>application</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>application</name>
    <description>Application endpoint</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>adapters-input</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>shared_model</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>adapters-output</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>application-services</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>aggregates</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I tried a lot of things and became a little desperate. It seems like there is an issue with seeing sibling-modules and child-modules, but I don't see why. Also, I don't understand why it is working smoothly from when ran from IntelliJ.

I greatly appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: You should run your app in production using `mvn boot:run`. Instead you should build a jar, ship that and run that with `java -jar your.jar` on the server. Finally the order of the modules in your maven pom do matter (in my experience, but things might have improved). Your application one should be the last one. Finally only your application project should have the spring boot maven plugin applied not your other projects. So basically you should remove that from your main and move that the the pom for application.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now it is working just fine. mvn boot:run is still not working for the same reason, but as this is not suggested anyways, I am good now. It is most of the time such a tiny issue...

Comment: The boot run is probably also due to the plugin being applied to all projects and I suspect only the application project has that. So you should only run that from within the application project and not the top level project.